# Python Flask Decorators and Apache mod_wsgi

Tags: python, apache, flask, decorator, mod-wsgi

I have created a fairly strait forward example of the Flask/Python application, and then I have decided to split code to the two files, so I have moved all decorators for Authentication to separate file, like following:

```
#### test.py
from flask import Flask, request, abort, request, make_response, url_for, jsonify
from flask.ext.httpauth import HTTPBasicAuth
import pypyodbc, json, collections, _db, _sc
from customauth import CustomHTTPBasicAuth

app = Flask(__name__)
app.debug = True

from werkzeug.debug import DebuggedApplication
application = DebuggedApplication(app, evalex=True)

@app.errorhandler(400)
def not_found(error): return make_response(jsonify( { 'error': 'Bad request' } ), 400)
@app.errorhandler(404)
def not_found(error): return make_response(jsonify( { 'error': 'Not found' } ), 404)

auth = CustomHTTPBasicAuth()

@app.route('/hello')
@auth.login_required
def hello_world():
    name = request.args.get('name','')
    return 'Hello ' + name + '!'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()



#### customauth.py
from flask import Flask, jsonify, make_response, request
from flask.ext.httpauth import HTTPBasicAuth
import md5, socket

class CustomHTTPBasicAuth(HTTPBasicAuth):
    def __init__(self):
    super(CustomHTTPBasicAuth, self).__init__()

        @self.get_password
        def get_password(username):
            if (md5.new(username).hexdigest() == '0cc175b9c0f1b6a831c399e269772661'): #'0cc175b9c0f1b6a831c399e269772661' is md5('a')
                return '0cc175b9c0f1b6a831c399e269772661'
            return None 

        @self.hash_password
        def custom_authenticate(password):
            return '0cc175b9c0f1b6a831c399e269772661'

        @self.error_handler
        def unauthorized():
            return make_response(jsonify( { 'error': 'Unauthorized access' } ), 401)

#### wsgi.py
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, "c:/testflask/test")

from flask1 import app
application = app
```

1. First issues is: this code works fine when executed with the **python test.py** 
   Authentication form will popup asking for username and password, after entering 'a','a' authentication will pass and result 'Hello + whatever' will display. 
   But when executed through Apache mod_wsgi it does not run as expected  authentication form will display unlimited number of times. 
   Please can someone explain this code running under python and not under mod_wsgi, and is there a way to fix this?
   I am thinking that I am doing something wrong with the decorators but I am not sure what, also it does not answer why it's running via python and not via mod_wsgi.
2. Another thing is how to get Debug page via apache mod_wsgi instead of "Internal Server Error" page? I have tried with 'werkzeug.debug' and some other suggested things from the internet but nothing really worked for me.

Thanks,

### #

I have found solution for the first bullet it is Apache settings only thing needed is to add WSGIPassAuthorization On in the config file.

Still trying to find solution for debugging...

Comment: I don't think it solves your issue, but you have defined the function ``not_found`` twice, one for 404s and one for 400s.

Comment: Also, please split each of your issues into separate questions.

Comment: Interesting enough 400, 404 works fine with the same name probably because it is wrapped with the decorator and therefore considered as anonymous function I have tried one way or another and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

The Flask debugger will likely not work if it detects that it is running in a multi process configuration as would often be the case for mod_wsgi if you are using embedded mode. Ensure you are using daemon mode of mod_wsgi:

```
WSGIDaemonProcess mysite
WSGIProcessGroup mysite
```

Note, do NOT set 'processes=1' to WSGIDaemonProcess. Let it default to 1. Using 'processes' option with any value will cause wsgi.multiprocess to be True which is possibly what is causing the Flask debugger to be disabled.